# Rancher - valid for ingress.local

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-ingress, rancher, cert-manager, rancher-rke

I'm trying to build the Rancher cluster (3 nodes). I setup it with Rancher signed SSL certificate. Everything is working fine except pods: cattle-node-agent which says this:

```
level=fatal msg="Get https://rancher-test.mycompany.com: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not rancher-test.mycompany.com".
```

I setup everything regards to documentations and use for rancher deployment and cert-manager official HELM repository. **Rancher version 2.4.5** - stable.

All hosts in the cluster are able to resolve: rancher-test.mycompany.com. For test I don't want to use CA signer cert.

CERT-MANAGER install via: `helm upgrade --install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --version v0.15.0`

RANCHER-SERVER install via: `helm upgrade --install rancher --namespace cattle-system tmp/rancher/ --set hostname=host1 --set hostname2=host2 --set hostname3=host3--set replicas=3 ignore_errors: True`

Does anyone have a similar issue? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem using both Linode and DigitalOcean and k8s cert-manager via nginx ingress and cert-manager.  It just started happening and production certificates are not being generated.

Comment: Fortunately, on production, we are about use signed by CA but on test, we are not able to fix it.

Comment: @JiříŠafář did you ever manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting the fake cert.

Please try the following helm upgrade --install rancher --namespace cattle-system tmp/rancher/ --set hostname=rancher-test.mycompany.com --set replicas=3

Also, please run kubectl -n cattle-system get ingress rancher -o yaml and verify the correct hostname.